# Regex for Replacing String with Incrementing Number

Tags: regex, replace, awk, sed, increment

Once upon a time I used UltraEdit for making this

```
text 1
text 2
text 3
text 4
...
```

from that

```
text REPLACE
text REPLACE
text REPLACE
text REPLACE
...
```

it was as easy as replace `REPLACE` with `\i`

now, how can I do this with eg. `sed`?

If you provide a solution, could you please add directions for filling the result with leading zeros?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use awk instead of sed for this:

```
awk '{ sub(/REPLACE/, ++i) } 1' file
text 1
text 2
text 3
text 4
...
```

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/fu6uo5)

Comment: Mh, doesn't work for me. Could you give a few explanations how this is supposed to do its job?

Comment: But it does not work any more if my data changes to `somethingelse REPLACE`. Could you please give a script that replaces REPLACE and is not dependant on other file content?

Comment: Well, it still is dependant on the spaces. But I can work around this. And I have no idea how this works and cannot learn from it. :( but anyway thanks for your help... Does it mean `if column 2 contains REPLACE then set column 2 to i++`? and what's the `1` good for?

Comment: ok check updated answer again to even take space out of equation. `1` in awk is called default action to print the record.

Comment: Sorry, I only looked at first part of your question as your desired output. So yes for leading zeroes `awk '{ sub(/REPLACE/, sprintf("%03d",++i)) } 1' file` can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
$ awk '{$NF=sprintf("%05d",++i)} 1' file
text 00001
text 00002
text 00003
text 00004
```

If not, edit your question to show some more truly representative sample input and expected output (and get rid of the `...`s if they don't literally exist in your input and output as they make your example non-testable).

Comment: Thanks guys, I use a combination of the two solutions now: `awk '{ sub(/REPLACE/, sprintf("%02d",++i)) } 1'`. I would like to accept both answers, but you can only accept one. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -i -pe 's/REPLACE/++$i/ge' file
```

For zero-padding to the minimum width (i.e. if there are 10 replacements, use field width 2):

```
perl -i -pe '
    BEGIN {
        $patt = "REPLACE"; 
        chomp( $n = qx(grep -co "$patt" file) ); 
        $n = int( log($n)/log(10) ) + 1;
    } 
    s/$patt/ sprintf("%0*d", $n, ++$i) /ge
' file
```